# Reference Book for Isometry

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, book-recommendation, isometry

Suggest me a good reference book for Isometries in $R^n$ which include Reflection map about a hyperplane W of $R^n$ through the origin and Isometry of plane.

Comment: You mean inversions?

Comment: i dont know what you mean by inversions by i want something related to Isometry:rotation,reflection.

Answer (score 0):

I got a reference book it includes rotations in $R^2$ and $R^3$.I found the book is very good and good for self study.The book is "QUATERNIONS 
AND ROTATION SEQUENCES" by Jack B.Kuipers